# Use liquid object in json scheme shopify

Tags: json, schema, shopify, liquid

Is there any option to use a liquid object in json scheme tag?
For example I have a product-template.liquid file which contains following schema:

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Product pages",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "text_custom_1",
      "label": "Custom text"
    },
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

What I would like to acheive is getting a dynamic id for the product as id for the custom field like so:

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Product pages",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "text_custom_1_{{%product.id%}}",
      "label": "Custom text"
    },
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

But that gives json syntax error. Is the above possible in some way?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option for using any liquid code inside the schema object.

It's better to use blocks if you want any dynamic content.

Comment: I dont know why you are saying this, as this is doable easily via Liquid template

Comment: @dExIT this answer was written 3 years ago and it's still true. Please read the docs https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/sections/section-schema#content where it's mentioned `The {% schema %} tag is a Liquid tag. However, it doesn’t output its contents, or render any Liquid included inside it.` so NO you still can't. Please double check your sources before bumping 3 year old answer.

Comment: Mate you write your own schema, just use if else, and pull variables, the principle itself works. as i stated my answer atleast shows how to pull per product results/content/meta

Comment: @dExIT I think you are confusing your terminology. What you are showing is `schema.org` it has nothing to do with the Shopify section schema. The `{% schema %}` tag is unique to the Shopify section files that controls what field are shown in the customization panel but what you are showing at the moment is schema that describes what is on the page... while they share the same name `schema` they have absolutely nothing in common other than that both of them are a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to write your own LD-JSON markup that pulls data from your SHopify stores options etc.

Please take a look at this example, add this to your Liquid Template place at bottom of DOM, before :

```
{% comment %}
  Article structured data
  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles
{% endcomment %}

{% if template contains 'article' %}
  {%- capture article_description  -%}
    {%- if article.excerpt != blank -%}
      {{ article.excerpt | strip_html }}
    {%- else -%}
      {{ article.content | truncatewords: 100 | strip_html }}
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endcapture -%}

  <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "BlogPosting",
      "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "{{ shop.url }}{{ article.url }}"
      },
      "headline": {{ article.title | json }},
      {% if article.image %}
        "image": {
          "@type": "ImageObject",
          "url": {{ article.image | img_url: '800x800' | prepend: 'https:' | json }},
          "height": 800,
          "width": 800
        },
      {% endif %}
      "datePublished": {{ article.published_at | date: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z' | json}},
      "dateModified": {{ article.published_at | date: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z' | json}},
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": {{ article.author | json }}
      },
      "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": {{ shop.name | json }},
        "logo": {
          "@type": "ImageObject",
          "url": {{ article.user.image | img_url: '200x200' | prepend: 'https:' | json }}
        }
      },
      "description": {{ article_description | json }}
    }
  </script>
{% endif %}

{% comment %}
  Breadcrumbs
  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs
{% endcomment %}

{%- if current_tags -%}
  {%- assign tag_names = current_tags | join: ', ' %}
  {% comment %}Converting an array to a handle converts it to a string{% endcomment %}
  {%- capture tag_handles -%}
    {%- for tag in current_tags -%}
      {{- tag | handle | append: '|' -}}
    {%- endfor -%}
  {%- endcapture -%}
{%- endif -%}

{% if collection.url == blank %}
  {% assign collection_url = '/collections/all' %}
{% else %}
  {% assign collection_url = collection.url %}
{% endif %}

{% if template.name == 'product' 
    or template.name == 'list-collections' 
    or template.name == 'collection' 
    or template.name == 'blog' 
    or template.name == 'article' 
    or template.name == 'search' 
    or template.name == 'cart' 
    or template.name == 'page'
%}

  <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [
      {% case template.name %}
        {% when 'product' %}
          {% if product.collections.size >= 1 %}
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": 1,
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/collections",
                "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.collections' | t | json }}
              }
            },
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": 2,
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/collections/{{ product.collections.first.handle }}",
                "name": {{ product.collections.first.title | json }}
              }
            },
          {% else %}
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": 1,
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/products",
                "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.products' | t | json }}
              }
            },
          {% endif %}
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": {% if product.collections.size >= 1 %}3{% else %}2{% endif %},
            "item": {
              "@id": "{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url | within: collection }}",
              "name": {{ product.title | json }}
            }
          }
        {% when 'list-collections' %}
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
              "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/collections",
              "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.collections' | t | json }}
            }
          }
          {% if current_page != 1 %}
            ,
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": 2,
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/collections",
                "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.page' | t: page: current_page | json }}
              }
            }
          {% endif %}
        {% when 'collection' %}
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
              "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/collections",
              "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.collections' | t | json }}
            }
          },
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "item": {
              "@id": "{{ shop.url }}{{ collection_url }}",
              "name": {{ collection.title | json }}
            }
          }
          {% if current_tags %}
            ,
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": 3,
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ shop.url }}{{ collection_url }}/{{- tag_handles | split: '|' | join: '+' -}}",
                "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.tags_html' | t: tags: tag_names | json }}
              }
            }
          {% endif %}
          {% if current_page != 1 %}
            {% if current_tags %}
              {% assign position = 4 %}
            {% else %}
              {% assign position = 3 %}
            {% endif %}
            ,
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": {{ position }},
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/collections?page={{ current_page }}",
                "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.page' | t: page: current_page | json }}
              }
            }
          {% endif %}
        {% when 'blog' or 'article' %}
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
              "@id": "{{ shop.url }}{{ blog.url }}",
              "name": {{ blog.title | json }}
            }
          }
          {% if template.name == 'article' %}
            ,
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": 2,
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ shop.url }}{{ article.url }}",
                "name": {{ article.title | json }}
              }
            }
          {% elsif current_tags %}
            ,
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": 2,
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ shop.url }}{{ blog.url }}/tagged/{{- tag_handles | split: '|' | join: '+' -}}",
                "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.tags_html' | t: tags: tag_names | json }}
              }
            }
          {% endif %}
          {% if current_page != 1 %}
            {% if current_tags %}
              {% assign position = 3 %}
              {%- capture url -%}
                {{ shop.url }}{{ blog.url }}/tagged/{{ tag_handles | split: '|' | join: '+' }}?page={{ current_page }}
              {%- endcapture -%}
            {% else %}
              {% assign position = 2 %}
                {%- capture url -%}
                {{ shop.url }}{{ blog.url }}?page={{ current_page }}
              {%- endcapture -%}
            {% endif %}
            ,
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": {{ position }},
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ url }}",
                "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.page' | t: page: current_page | json }}
              }
            }
          {% endif %}
        {% when 'search' %}
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
              "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/search",
              "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.search' | t | json }}
            }
          }
          {% if search.performed %}
            {
              "@type": "ListItem",
              "position": 2,
              "item": {
                "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/search?q={{ search.terms }}",
                "name": {{ search.terms | json }}
              }
            }
            {% if current_page != 1 %}
              {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 3,
                "item": {
                  "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/search?page={{ current_page }}&q={{ search.terms }}",
                  "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.page' | t: page: current_page | json }}
                }
              }
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% when 'cart' %}
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
              "@id": "{{ shop.url }}/cart",
              "name": {{ 'structured_data.breadcrumbs.cart' | t | json }}
            }
          }
        {% when 'page' %}
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
              "@id": "{{ page.url }}",
              "name": {{ page.title | json }}
            }
          }
        {% else %}
        {% endcase %}
      ]
    }
  </script>
{% endif %}

{% comment %}
  Product structured data
  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products
{% endcomment %}

{% if template contains 'product' %}
  {% assign selected_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant | default: product.variants.first %}
  {% assign product_image = selected_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
  {%- capture product_name -%}
    {{ product.title }}
    {%- if selected_variant.title != 'Default Title' and selected_variant.option1 == 'Default Title' -%}
      - {{ selected_variant.title }}
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endcapture -%}

  {%- assign now = 'now' | date: '%Y-%m-%d' | split: '-' -%}
  {% capture year_from_now %}{{ now[0] | plus: 1 }}-{{ now[1] }}-{{ now[2] | at_most: 28 }}{% endcapture %}

  <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": {{ product_name | strip_newlines | json }},
    "image": {{ product_image | img_url: '1024x1024' | prepend: 'https:' | json }},
    {% if product.description != blank %}
      "description": {{ product.description | json }},
    {% endif %}
    {% if product.vendor %}
      "brand": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "name": {{ product.vendor | json }}
      },
    {% endif %}
    {% if selected_variant.sku != blank %}
      "sku": {{ selected_variant.sku | json }},
    {% endif %}
    {% if selected_variant.barcode != blank %}
      "mpn": {{ selected_variant.barcode | json }},
    {% endif %}
    "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "priceCurrency": {{ cart.currency.iso_code | json }},
      "price": {{ selected_variant.price | divided_by: 100.0 | json }},
      "availability": "http://schema.org/{% if selected_variant.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}",
      "url": "{{ shop.url }}{{ selected_variant.url }}",
      "seller": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": {{ shop.name | json }}
      },
      "priceValidUntil": {{ year_from_now | json }}
    }
  }
  </script>
{% endif %}

{% comment %}
  Store information
  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitename
{% endcomment %}

<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "name": "{{ shop.name }}",
    "url": "{{ shop.url }}"
  }
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@type": "Organization",
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "name": "{{shop.name}}",
  "logo": {
      "@type": "imageObject",
      "url": "https:{{ 'logo.png' | asset_img_url: '300x240' | split: '?' | first }}",
      "height": "300px",
      "width": "240px"
   },
  "url": "{{ shop.url }}"
}
</script>
```

Originally first seen here : https://gist.github.com/wmulligan87/1368b434a880b2517fc2152989fbd2df

This should give you all what you need, hopefully someone will find this helpful as this solved a lot of issues.